# Set a Group number when cumulative column less than or equal to target

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have a column which contains how many sub_links a website has.

My table schema is id, sub_link, link

```
id  sub_link link group
1   5   link1.com   1
2   2   link2.com   2
3   4   link3.com   3
4   1   link4.com   3
4   1   link4.com   3
5   2   link5.com   4
6   4   link6.com   5
7   3   link7.com   6
7   3   link7.com   6
```

I want to add a column with group number when the total of sub_link is equal or less than 5 along with avoiding duplicates.

I don't know where to start since I can only write select statements and make some joins.
Maybe there is a way using Window Function or CTE which I prefer to further my experience.

Here is a fiddle link

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6rmtcazWaWvLULZ5QgpmSb/1

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are the values 1-6 instead of 1-7?

Comment: This doesn't line up perfectly but it close? `sum(sub_links) over (order by id) / 5`

Comment: I think this one is closer: `(sum(sub_links) over (order by id) - 1) / 5 + 1` There will be a problem with this though for the sets of rows with the same `id`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I explained the logic more in details in a comment at the first answer.
I don't have DDL/DML just this table exported to me and have this task to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment below, I'm not sure how to do this outside of keeping track of the rolling Sub_link sum in a separate temp table.  An example of this below. IF you only needed to keep track of the Sub_links for current record and previous, may be way to accomplish with single query utilizing [LAG function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [Test]
GO

USE [Test]
GO

CREATE TABLE [Test] (
    ID INT
  , Sub_Links TINYINT
  , Link VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO [Test]
VALUES (1, 5, 'link1.com')
    , (2, 2, 'link2.com') 
    , (3, 4, 'link3.com')
    , (4, 1, 'link4.com')
    , (4, 1, 'link4.com')
    , (5, 2, 'link5.com')
    , (6, 4, 'link6.com')
    , (7, 3, 'link7.com')
    , (7, 3, 'link7.com');

SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
CREATE TABLE #Staging
(
      ID INT
    , Link VARCHAR(100)
    , Sub_Links INT
    , GroupNum INT
    , SublinkRollingSum TINYINT
)
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [StagingOrder] ON #Staging(ID, Link) --Since need to guarantee order, doing this upfront should be more efficient
GO

INSERT INTO #Staging(ID, Link, Sub_Links)
SELECT DISTINCT --Don't include duplicate records
      ID
    , Link
    , Sub_Links
FROM Test
ORDER BY ID, Link
GO
--CREATE INDEX [GroupIndex] ON #Staging(GroupNum, SublinkRollingSum)--Intended to improve performance of below while loop
--GO

WITH FirstRecord AS
(
    SELECT TOP(1) *
    FROM #Staging
    ORDER BY ID, Link
)
UPDATE FirstRecord
SET GroupNum = 1, SublinkRollingSum = Sub_Links --This is the starting point

DECLARE 
      @CurrentID INT
    , @CurrentLink VARCHAR(100)
    , @CurrentGroup INT
    , @SublinkRollingSum TINYINT

SELECT TOP(1) 
      @CurrentID = ID
    , @CurrentLink = Link
    , @CurrentGroup = GroupNum
    , @SublinkRollingSum = SublinkRollingSum
FROM #Staging
ORDER BY ID, Link

WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE #Staging
    SET   SublinkRollingSum = @SublinkRollingSum
        , GroupNum = @CurrentGroup
    WHERE ID = @CurrentID
        AND Link = @CurrentLink

    SELECT TOP(1)
          @CurrentID = ID
        , @CurrentLink = Link
        , @CurrentGroup = 
            CASE 
                WHEN (@SublinkRollingSum + Sub_Links <= 5) 
                    THEN @CurrentGroup
                ELSE @CurrentGroup + 1
            END
        , @SublinkRollingSum = 
            CASE 
                WHEN (@SublinkRollingSum + Sub_Links <= 5) 
                    THEN @SublinkRollingSum + Sub_Links
                ELSE Sub_Links
            END
    FROM #Staging
    WHERE ID > @CurrentID 
        OR (ID = @CurrentID AND Link <> @CurrentLink)
    ORDER BY ID, Link
END

SELECT 
      t.ID
    , t.Sub_Links
    , t.Link
    , s.GroupNum
FROM #Staging S
    JOIN Test t ON s.ID = t.ID
        AND s.Link = t.Link
ORDER BY t.ID, t.Link

DROP TABLE #Staging

--DROP DATABASE [Test]
```

[image: Screenshot of result set from SSMS]

Comment: Thank you for this query.
Correct I need to add a column, which contains a group number, where each group contains 5 at most.

In my example first obstacle is the duplication then, I will manually write the logic
id = 1, sub = 5 then group = 1
id =2, sub = 2 + previous 5 = more than 5 then new group = 2 (because 1 is full)
id = 3, sub = 4 + prev 2 = 6 more than 5 then new group = 3 (group 2 has only id 2 because with 4 become more than 5)
id = 4 (duplicate then avoid the first or second row), sub = 1, also group 3 because prev 4 + 1 = 5 

next will be group 4 and so on.

Comment: I hop I explained well, this is the logic of the group column

Comment: @hatahetahmad - to get group is more than just the previous sub_link value considered?  E.g. id = 1, sub = 1, group = 1; id = 2, sub = 2, group = 1 (because 2 + 1 <=5); id = 3, sub = 1, group = 1?? because 1 + 2 + 1 <= 5??  Then what about this case: id = 1, sub = 1, group = 1; id = 2, sub = 3, group = 1, id = 3, sub = 2, group = 1 because 2 + 1 <= 5 or group =2 because 1 + 3 + 2 > 5??? 

Also, is the value of sub_link ever 0?

Comment: Thank you Dear, This is correct group =2 because 1 + 3 + 2 > 5, also there is no case of 0 and there is no case when a sub link is more than 5.
sub link always [1:5]